# Lag when switching windows

Tags: boot, nvidia, xorg, freeze

Everything was working fine but today when I booted up ubuntu it started lagging a lot especially when switching windows or if the window is maximized also if I click and drag the mouse.
When I switch windows it (I think) re-renders the window and it's very slow at doing that it does it like old-school TVs that render images top to bottom and it's very noticeable.
I checked the processes and Xorg takes up a high CPU percentage.
I tried rebooting.
I also updated video drivers to the latest version.
I have quite a capable computer.

```
CPU: i7-6700
GPU: GTX 970
16 GB of ram
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
```

I should also note that I boot my ubuntu from an external hard drive.

Comment: try to disable Animations in Tweaks, and see if that helps

Comment: It didn't help, same issue.

Comment: I have the same problem. I noted that the process that is consuming CPU is `/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3`. To disable animations doesn't help too.